# GC issues compiling a large scala monorepo

Tags: scala

Scala version=2.12.15
SBT version=1.4.9
JVM=1.8
GC=ParallelGC ( marksweep/scavenge )
Heap size=14GB
Monorepo is full of spark code

Files to compile 34013 over 3-4 subprojects

What we've noticed is the gradual increase on old-gen space that doesn't clear out even though GC's are constantly happening which suggests there are a lot of live objects

A heap dump was taken

jmap -histo ( 3rd column is size in megabytes )

```
13: 1209208 181.843 [Ljava.lang.Object;
12: 8881966 203.292 xsbti.api.NameHash
11: 9080251 207.83 scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1
10: 7052557 215.227 scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Literal
9: 6539689 249.469 scala.reflect.internal.Trees$TypeTree
8: 10487573 320.055 scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$TypeHistory
7: 4839129 332.277 scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$TermSymbol
6: 10500404 400.559 scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Apply
5: 10728133 409.246 scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Ident
4: 30407384 695.97 java.lang.String
3: 18842332 718.778 scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Select
2: 35977908 823.469 scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
1: 30412139 1942.91 [C
```

When we analyzed the retained sizes of various classes, `scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon` was retaining around 5G of heap

I'm curious to understand how scalac works to get to the bottom of this. Worst case perhaps we do need 14G of heap to compile our monorepo

Comment: 2.12.5 is ancient — maybe try 2.12.17 and see if that helps? sbt 1.4.9 is also ancient; you might also try upgrading to 1.8.2. It's possible neither upgrade will help, but regardless, those are the first things I'd suggest trying, since otherwise you're troubleshooting stuff that, quite conceivably, was already fixed long ago.

Comment: @SethTisue my bad, we use 2.12.15

Comment: Java 11 GC behaviour is also much changed (often improved) from Java 8.